# confused by clicked() and clicked(bool) in qt 4 signal and slot

Tags: qt, click, signals-slots

I am using qt 4.8.6 and visual studio 2008 to develop a project and confused by clicked() and clicked(bool). While building a connection for an object which will emit a signal:

```
connect(sender, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), receiver, SLOT(myslot()));
```

will trigger myslot(); and

```
connect(sender, SIGNAL(clicked()), receiver, SLOT(myslot()));
```

will not trigger it. However, I find other many examples about connect which all use clicked() not clicked(bool). **Why cannot I use clicked()?**
I look through Qt Assistant about:

> **void QAbstractButton::clicked ( bool checked = false ) [signal]**
>
> This signal is emitted when the button is activated (i.e. pressed down then released while the mouse cursor is inside the button), when the shortcut key is typed, or when click() or animateClick() is called. Notably, this signal is not emitted if you call setDown(), setChecked() or toggle().
>
> If the button is checkable, checked is true if the button is checked,
> or false if the button is unchecked.

I cannot find its reason. At the same time, **what are the differences of the "checked" and "unchecked"?**

By the way, I build a connect by pressing the left mouse button and drag the cursor. Another way is to rightclick the object, then the context menu will applear "go to slot", but my Qt Designer(4.8.6) will not. **How to deal with it?**

3 quesions hope to get help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not see any difference between your first and second connections.

Comment: sorry, they are clicked() and clicked(bool) and I type them by mistake.

Comment: What does the `connect` statement return? Does it return `false`?

Comment: I don't see any reason why the code snippets you gave shouldn't work, the origin of your issue must therefore be found somewhere else. Provide a [mcve] if you expect helpful answers instead of guessing. It would also be of interest if there is any console output of your application. And make sure to read and understand the [Signals & Slots documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) before messing around with them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand the question(s), <strike>but the reason you can't connect to a `clicked()` signal is because there is no such thing... the function profile is clearly `clicked(bool)`</strike>  ([see docs](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked)).

Qt will only show a runtime error when it can't connect signal/slot (qWarning to stderr), it is not obvious at compile-time.  Try examining the program output for warnings.

*Edit: removed misleading information.*

Comment: sorry, I am still confused. I wonder why connect(sender, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), receiver, SLOT(myslot())); can trigger myslot() while connect(sender, SIGNAL(clicked(), receiver, SLOT(myslot())); cannot do. I have read the docs about void QAbstractButton::clicked(bool checked = false) but cannot find out the reason.

Comment: I find many example code which use clicked() not clicked(bool), such as     `connect(sourceButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(chooseSource()));
    connect(operatorComboBox, SIGNAL(activated(int)),
            this, SLOT(recalculateResult()));
    connect(destinationButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            this, SLOT(chooseDestination()));` (http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-painting-imagecomposition-example.html) @Max Paperno @eyllanesc

Comment: No, it should work. It works for me. And it is also [used in the docs like that](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect).

Comment: The signal has a default parameter, it can be used both as `SIGNAL(clicked())` and `SIGNAL(clicked(bool))`. See the general [Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots-with-default-arguments) documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same phenomenon too.
I think clicked(bool) and clicked(bool = false) is different.
The signal has different events.
I guess your "myslot()" may trigger the second event.